# XMPP: How to parse XMPPMessage element

Tags: objective-c, xmpp, nsxmlelement

I'm getting the following xml format for every message coming from xmpp

```
- (void)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didReceiveMessage:(XMPPMessage *)message
{
 NSLog(@"Message %@",message);        
}
```

In console its printing

```
<message
    xmlns="jabber:client" from="10000006956@xmpp-dev.peeks.com" to="10000006956@xmpp-dev.peeks.com/mobile">
    <result
        xmlns="urn:xmpp:mam:tmp" id="1483781596098940">
        <forwarded
            xmlns="urn:xmpp:forward:0">
            <message
                xmlns="jabber:client" from="10000006931@xmpp-dev.peeks.com/mobile" to="10000006956@xmpp-dev.peeks.com" type="chat">
                <body>Hi</body>
                <delay
                    xmlns="urn:xmpp:delay" from="xmpp-dev.peeks.com" stamp="2016-12-22T04:50:17.023Z">Offline Storage
                </delay>
            </message>
            <delay
                xmlns="urn:xmpp:delay" from="xmpp-dev.peeks.com" stamp="2017-01-07T09:33:16.099Z">
            </delay>
        </forwarded>
    </result>
</message>
```

I want to fetch "from", "to", "body", and "stamp" from every message and i did the following

```
NSXMLElement *body = message;
    NSXMLElement *messageb  = [body elementForName:@"result" xmlns:@"urn:xmpp:mam:tmp"];
    NSXMLElement *forwa=[messageb elementForName:@"forwarded" xmlns:@"urn:xmpp:forward:0"];
    NSXMLElement *msg=[forwa elementForName:@"message" xmlns:@"jabber:client"];
    NSXMLElement *TD=[forwa elementForName:@"delay" xmlns:@"urn:xmpp:delay"];

    NSString *from=[[msg elementForName:@"from" xmlns:@"jabber:client"] stringValue];
    NSString *to=[[msg elementForName:@"to" xmlns:@"jabber:client"] stringValue];
    NSString *bodyq=[[msg elementForName:@"body"] stringValue];
    NSString *stmp=[[TD elementForName:@"stamp" xmlns:@"urn:xmpp:delay"] stringValue];
    NSString *final=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"From: %@\nTo: %@\nBody: %@\nStamp: %@",from,to,bodyq,stmp];
    NSLog(@"forwa %@", final);
```

I can able to print only the message body and the log prints like

```
From: (null)
To: (null)
Body: hi
Stamp: (null)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix to search for attributes: elements are the nodes (like Body, Result etc.) while others are just attributes of previous elements.

```
NSString *from=[[msg attributeForName:@"from"] stringValue];
    NSString *to=[[msg attributeForName:@"to"] stringValue];
    NSString *stmp=[[TD attributeForName:@"stamp"] stringValue];
```

Edited (sorry, my last work with ObjectiveC it's really old).

`xml namespace` it's about `element` and not `attributes`.

If you didn't get again, try passing by NSXMLNode

```
NSXMLNode *fromNode = [msg attributeForName:@"from"];
NSString *from = [fromNode stringValue];
```

Comment: Its giving error No Visible @interface for 'DDXMLElement' declares the selector 'attributeForName:xmlns:'

Comment: just removed xmlns:@"jabber:client" from every line then its worked fine update ur answer toooo

Comment: Will you tell me how to fetch those values from below xml
<message
 xmlns="jabber:client" from="10000006949@xmpp-dev.peeks.com/96863631127022532144930" to="10000006964@xmpp-dev.peeks.com" lang="en" id="0pMJ6-54" type="chat">
 <archived
  xmlns="urn:xmpp:mam:tmp" by="xmpp-dev.peeks.com" id="1484052788873225">
 </archived>
 <stanza-id
  xmlns="urn:xmpp:sid:0" by="xmpp-dev.peeks.com" id="1484052788873225">
 </stanza-id>
 <body>xdxz</body>
 <thread>7e396ecf-e446-4c01-9257-c61b3bf201f4</thread>
</message>

Comment: Too long for a comment. Put your element in an object (example: NSXMLElement *forwa=[messageb elementForName:@"forwarded" xmlns:@"urn:xmpp:forward:0"]; will contains from <forwarded> up to </forwarded>, then get the element or the attribute as before :)

Comment: @MrPk If you got the answer of your problem. Please help me .https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44129790/how-to-parse-xmlns-message-in-swift3?noredirect=1#comment75280205_44129790

Answer (score 2):

For swift 5:

```
func xmppStream(_ sender: XMPPStream, didReceive message: XMPPMessage) {
        if let msg = message.body {
            if let from = message.attribute(forName: "from")?.stringValue{
                print("msg: \(msg), \(from)")
            }
        }
    }
```